# IF (there are three or more developed cells in the Moore Neighbourhood of a cell) THEN (the cell is developed)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster-calculator

I need to create an expression for that principle, so far I have figured out

```
CON ("FocalStatisticsSum" >= 3,"FocalStatisticsSum"="FocalStatisticsSum"+1)
```

Although I pretty sure I am missing things, and I am not including the requirement of More neighbourhood in the expression (I don't know how to).

Also I am not sure that  >= 3 is Ok for this purpose.

Finally, how would I translate "developed"

Could somebody tell me what would be a good expression for this?

Note: Moore neigbourhood is [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focal Statistics and Raster Calculator are fairly different tools.

First, you need to have a raster of cells that can be used to determined whether it's developed -- for a simple example, "house" (1) or "not house" (0). Run [Focal Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000qs000000.htm) on this data. Use a rectangular neighborhood (3 by 3 cells), statistics type SUM. I think this may be what you actually want as a result (depending on what existing data you have).

However, if you want to have a simpler "developed" vs. "not developed" raster, the next step is to run [Raster Calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Raster_Calculator/009z000000z7000000/) to find all cells with 3 or more "house" cells in their Moore neighborhood. If the raster `FocalStatistics` is greater than or equal to 3, then the value is 1, otherwise the value is 0:

```
Con("FocalStatistics" >= 3, 1, 0)
```